# Implicit conversions: Datetime-to-INT vs INT-to-Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble understanding why the query below is considered to be converting an integer into a datetime rather than converting a datetime into an integer.

In my head I'm reading this as converting a datetime to an integer because I'm setting the datetime equal to an integer. So why would it be the opposite? I could just flip the way I think about it but my hopes were that somebody can explain this so that I can think about it in the proper manner.

I would like to know in order to get a better grip on when implicit conversions are allowed vs when they aren't allowed.

```
DECLARE @theDateTime AS datetime
DECLARE @theInteger AS INT = 122811
SET  @theDateTime = @theInteger
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*considered*"? By whom? Where?

Comment: Dont mix other data types with ```DATE``` fields.

Comment: Seems you are looking for [data-type-precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, *not* an equality operator. This confusion has spurred some languages to adopt clearer symbols for assignment (like `<=` or even an explicit `←`) to emphasize the directionality -- but not many, and T-SQL isn't one of them. In this case there can be no other semantics than (implicitly) converting an integer to a datetime. That this conversion is allowed at all is arguably a misfeature, and one not adopted by the newer date/time types (`DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME2`, `DATETIMEOFFSET`).

Comment: @PM 77-1, by SQL Server. I know this because when I do the opposite of the query I provided, it throws an error "datetime to int is not allowed." Therefore the query I provided must be "int to datetime" (even though it seems like it shouldn't be)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, you have

```
@theDateTime AS datetime
@theInteger AS INT
```

By the end of line 2, their **values** are

```
@theDateTime = NULL
@theInteger = 122811
```

When you `SET @theDateTime = @theInteger`, you are literally telling the server "SET my datetime variable TO THE VALUE (122811)", but 122811 is not a valid datetime value; to succeed, the server must first convert your value to the same type as your desired destination.

By the end of line 3, their values are now

```
@theDateTime = 2236-03-31 00:00:00.000
@theInteger = 122811
```

You tried to set an integer value *into* your datetime field; ergo, the server had to convert your integer ***into*** a datetime value so it would fit in your datetime field.

TLDR: The left side is your destination. So, you're converting the right side into your left side so it fits.

Answer (score 1):

Basically datetime is integer in the background. It is storing the number of days since 1900-01-01. Due to this reason, when you store it as 0, it is adding 0 days to `1900-01-01`. D

```sql
DECLARE @theDateTime AS datetime
set @theDateTime = 0
SELECT @theDateTime

--1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

set @theDateTime = 1
SELECT @theDateTime

--1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

As you are assigning 122811, it is adding 122811 days to `1900-01-01`.

```sql
DECLARE @theDateTime AS datetime
DECLARE @theInteger AS INT = 122811
SET  @theDateTime = @theInteger
SELECT @theDateTime

--2236-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

But, if you try the other way around, You will get error.

```sql
DECLARE @theInteger AS INT
SET @theInteger = '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000'
SELECT @theInteger
```

> --Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000' to data type
> int.

Thanks to @Jeroen Mostert, If you want to do conversion to INT from datetime, you have to do it explicitly.

```sql
DECLARE @theInteger AS INT
SET @theInteger = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
SELECT @theInteger

--0
```

Comment: T-SQL has no `DATETIME` literals; that the string doesn't convert is obvious. To make the last example relevant, it should be something like `SET @theInteger = CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000')` (or just `SET @theInteger = @theDateTime`), It will then complain that there is no *implicit* conversion; you can still convert explicitly using `SET @theInteger = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000'))` (not that you should *want* to do this).

Answer (score 0):

in a SET statement the left hand side of ***=*** acts like a container that holds the value and the right side of ***=*** is the value that gets stored in the container.

So in your case the container is @theDateTime and the value you are assigning to the container is @theInteger.

Comment: So by the sounds of that, you're agreeing with what I said?

Comment: @NickT No, in your SET statement theDateTime is like a glass and theInteger is like water. when you pour the water into the glass the water is transforming into glass shape. that is the integer is implicitly converting into datetime format.